# constant capacity vector in class

Tags: c++, vector

I want to make a vector in private part of a class that hold only 10 integers 
but I get  " syntax error 'constant' " while making this vector in the private part of class.
I know that I can use a constant array instead of vector but why I can't use vector with constant capacity in a class? 
also if I make this vector in main() function every thing is fine but in the class I get this error!

```
class A
{
public:
// constructor 
private:
std::vector<int> tests(10); // here I get error
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the error? I can't help but notice you left out a semi-colon after `std::vector<int> tests(10)`... If your real code doesn't have that problem, you need to post a *real* [MCVE].

Comment: I am not sure but, isn't the purpose of the vectors are being dynamic,  maybe it doesn't support  constant values, but as I say I am only making predictions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) doesn't support parentheses initializer, but only brace or equals initializer.

> Through a default member initializer, which is simply a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration, which is used if the member is omitted in the member initializer list

Note that for `std::vector`, using brace initializer might lead to effect you don't want. (e.g. `std::vector<int>{10}` initializes a `vector` with 1 element with value `10`.) You can use equals initializer like

```
std::vector<int> tests = std::vector<int>(10);
```

BTW: If the size is fixed, you can use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

```
std::array<int, 10> tests;
```

Comment: No, that's not the issue here. Remember, this is inside a class. You can't call a constructor from the declaration of member variables. At least, not in certain versions of C++. Unless it's a constant, of course.

Comment: @Chipster Sorry I didn't get your point, do you mean default member initializer is invalid in C++?

Comment: I've done more research, and I may be slightly off. After C++11 it looks like it's okay. Pre C++11, something like `class foo { int member = 3; };` is not okay unless `member` is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The initialization of your member variable must be in the constructor list of your class.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(); // contructor
private:
    std::vector<int> tests;
};

A::A() :
tests(10)
{
   // constructor logic
}
```

Comment: No actually  this vector should hold just 10 objects of another class and there is no relation with its constructor

Comment: Since C++11, a member can have an initializer with its declaration, which will be used whenever a constructor doesn't specify how to initialize that member.

Comment: @meysamimani - you declared it as a vector of ints.  But your comment implies you want it to be a vector of something else.

Comment: yes I just write an example of code that cause problem. even if I change int to something else still there is problem Thank you for your comment .